# Why is the "Add Note" button giving an exception and printing null on the console?

Tags: html, forms, button

I am trying to add a note using Add Note Button but it is throwing an `exception`. I handled the error using try...catch block but the note written in Add Note Button is not added and printing `null` on console.
[JSBin](https://jsbin.com/qotahilete/edit?html,js) for my project:

Comment: See how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

This piece:

```
if(notes =='')
{
    notesObj = [];
}
else{
    notesObj = JSON.parse(notes);
}
```

is the problem. If there's nothing in the local storage, `notes` will be null, which means `notesObj == ''` will be false, and the code will break. You need to change the test so it detects null (and other falsy values) as such:

```
if(!notes)
{
    notesObj = [];
}
else{
    notesObj = JSON.parse(notes);
}
```

There's another problem. This line:

```
localStorage.setItem('notes', JSON.stringify(notes));
```

makes no sense. You're setting the item notes in the local storage as the converted json of the `notes` variable, which is already a JSON string, so it'll fail horribly. What you really want to do is stringify the `notesObj` variable, which is the array with the actual notes. Change that line to:

```
localStorage.setItem('notes', JSON.stringify(notesObj));
```

And that's it. Make those changes and your code will work.